# LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE not disables HW acceleration on some devices in some time

Tags: android, view, hardware-acceleration

I use clipPath for clip round from canvas and then drive:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{   
    float radius = ((float) getWidth()) / 2;
    clipPath.reset();
    clipPath.addCircle(radius, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Of couse, I set View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE for this view in constructor and in XML.

But on some devices (Android 3):

```
LENOVO K1
acer A501
samsung GT-P6200
ZTE V9S
```

throwns exception when I try to draw clipped canvas:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at android.view.GLES20Canvas.clipPath(GLES20Canvas.java:303)
at com.myapp.ui.RoundedCornerImageView.onDraw(RoundedCornerImageView.java:35)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9292)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8755)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2296)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8719)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8753)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2029)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9399)
at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3315)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8755)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2296)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8719)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2296)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8719)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2296)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8719)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2296)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8719)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2296)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8719)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2296)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8719)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2296)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8719)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2296)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8719)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:691)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1624)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1440)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2070)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4143)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Interestingly, the app crashes not immediately, but after some time. For stack above start time is 2013-03-31 16:04:04, crashe time is 2013-03-31 16:18:47. Although RoundedCornerImageView is displayed at MainActivity!

Answer (score 1):

I found this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20474

It fixed in only in 4.1 (API 16).

I decide turn on HW acceleration only for API 16 and higher

In manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="@bool/hw_acceleration"
```

In values/constants.xml:

```
<bool name="hw_acceleration">false</bool>
```

In values-16/constants.xml:

```
<bool name="hw_acceleration">true</bool>
```

I hope, this will be works!